# Why am I getting a msinet error 339 on windows 7/8

Tags: vb6, msinet

On some systems windows 7/8 my vb6 application gets the msinet error 339. 
Component ‘MSINET.OCX’ or one of its dependencies not correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid.

I'm wondering if I need that ocx. 
How can I tell if I am using the msinet.ocx? And whether I need it?
I notice Microsoft Internet Controls checked as a component and also Microsoft Internet Transfer Control 6.0 (SP6). Are either of these MSInet.ocx?

Comment: The ITC (often called INet) is indeed part of the msinet.ocx library.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Internet Transfer Control 6.0 (SP6). Load the OCX as a reference by filename and it tell you it's name.

Rebuild the setup program, msinet is normally included if used.

Answer (score 0):

Registration issues can also crop up relating to Internet Explorer 10. If the OCX is present on the systems in question but seemingly not registered, then the solution can be to uninstall IE 10 (normally best to remove all versions of IE that Windows will let you - they're found under Windows Updates, rather than programs, incidentally). After removing these versions, you are free to reinstall the latest version of IE.